# Package isodate Warning: Language english unknown to isodate

Tags: bibliographies, babel, date, url, isodate

Consider the following input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib} % Multilingual bibliographies
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[num,ngerman]{isodate} % Tune the output format of dates according to language
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @unpublished{Reynolds_2008,
    Author = {John Charles Reynolds},
    Language = {english},
    Title = {An Introduction to {Separation} {Logic}},
    Url = {http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jcr/copenhagen08.pdf},
    Urldate = {2014-09-23}
      }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{Reynolds_2008}
\setbibliographyfont{urldate}{\printdate}
\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

After compiling with the standard pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex loop, I get the following warning in the log:

```
Package isodate Warning: Language english unknown to isodate.
(isodate)                Using default format on input line 22.
```

I get a similar message if I use `american` or `USenglish` instead of `english`. Somehow, I cannot believe that isodate knows nothing about English. It would really <strike>suck</strike> surprise me a lot. What does this warning tell me? Can I simply ignore it? Or is the package simply broken and it's better to switch to something else?

(Remark: This is simply a MWE. In reality, I use svmono instead of article with tons of other packages and huge multilingual bibliography.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass `english` as an option to `isodate`. You should load it with:

```
\usepackage[num,english,ngerman]{isodate}
```

(the last language is the default).

Alternatively, you can pass the languages as options to `documentclass`, which feeds both `isodate` and `babel`.

```
\documentclass[english,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[num]{isodate}
....
```

Comment: I don't really know `svmono`, but, AFAIK, options passed to documentclass are available as global options, which means that they will be available to all packages loaded later. So I'd say yes, why not. Or you can pass them all to `isodate`.

Comment: Well, you can always add the languages as options to `isodate`... (as long as they are know to `isodate`).

Comment: The request seems strange. You load `babelbib` to have multilingual bibliographies. You load `isodate` to have localized dates. And at the end of the day, you want the dates in a single format? Anyway, that's another issue, for which you should ask a new question, if you don't find an answer around.